# Flutter 3D Design Page Implementation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I was wondering if there is any solution or way to implement 3d designs roadmap in flutter. For example like a design below which is a horizontal scrollable page that contains dynamic elements and the number of elements in the screen can be dynamic. Can any one suggest me how to do it and give me hints on how to implement such design?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stack
The children of stack will be

1. Horizontal scroll singleChildScrollView
   2.Other UI elements like pop up

Horizontal singleChildScrollView will contain another stack which will hold the following

1. Bg images which is tiled after certain length (like a carousel without padding)
2. Level buttons at specific positions.

Comment: Thanks, That actually worked for me!!